# AWS CloudTrail Create API for Go SDK throwing error mesage "InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket: "

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to create a cloudtrail using Go SDK. Successfully able to connect AWS without any issue by following AWS doc.

I Followed below steps for creating a trail

Step1 - Created S3 Bucket, so that all trail log files can be placed in this bucket.

**CreateS3Bucket: Code**

```
func CreateS3Bucket(bucketName string) error {
bucketName := "s3-bucket-123"
svc := s3.New(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-1")}))

params := &s3.CreateBucketInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucketName), // Required
}
resp, err1 := svc.CreateBucket(params)

if err1 != nil {
    // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
    // Message from an error.
    log.Errorf("S3 Bucket Creation Fails: %s", err1.Error())
    errs := errors.New("500")
    return errs
}

// Pretty-print the response data.
log.Infof("Bucket Successfully created: %s", resp)
return nil
}
```

**Success Response:**

```
{\n  Location: \"/s3-bucket-123\"\n}"
```

Step2 - Create CloudTrail

**CreateCloudTrail:** **Code**

```
func (ref *AwsCloudTrail) CreateCloudTrail(bucketName, trailName string) error {
svc := cloudtrail.New(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-1")}))

//bucketName is "s3-bucket-123" and trailName is cloudtrail123

params := &cloudtrail.CreateTrailInput{
    Name:                       aws.String(trailName), // Required
    S3BucketName:               aws.String(bucketName), // Required
}

resp, errs := svc.CreateTrail(params)

if errs != nil {
    // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
    // Message from an error.
    log.Errorf("Error while creating trail %v",errs.Error())
    err := errors.New("500")
    return err
}

// Pretty-print the response data.
log.Infof("create trail response: %s",resp)

return nil
}
```

**Response**

```
"Error while creating trail InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket: s3-bucket-123\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: 203d63d6-51ea-11e6-bb2c-b5d25b86e418"
```

Can anyone please tell me where i am doing wrong. what S3 Policy do i need to specify while creating Trail

Any Help/Suggestion is really appreciated

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cloudtrail/#CloudTrail.CreateTrail

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.CreateBucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cloud Trail should have this policy for the S3 bucket. Follow this guide there are different options in the step.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/create-s3-bucket-policy-for-cloudtrail.html

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName/[optional prefix]/AWSLogs/myAccountID/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.
The Guide that you provided shows steps to be followed through AWS console. Is there something similar that i can do through aws-go-sdk. I mean adding/specifying S3 bucket policy through Go-SDK

Comment: Check this https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/tree/master/service/iam there is a example file where you can attached different policies check examples_test.go file.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it worked for me, able to create Trail successfully now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that after you add the policy mentioned in the accepted answer that there is a match between your bucket's `name`, `prefix` and `accountID` and the values specified here:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName/<prefix>/AWSLogs/myAccountID/*"
```

Also make sure that the `"*"` postfix exist.

Wrong configuration there will lead to the same error.